# Can I exchange a github access token with raw file token

Tags: github, github-enterprise, octokit

Does anyone know if there is any information about how the raw tokens are created?

TLDR is that I want to create links to files (specifically images) from private repos with the raw token attached. I need this to happen automatically, I do not want to "click the raw button" to get the token, that being said I do have access to the logged in users personal access token. Can I use this access token in order to automatically create a raw link with the raw token attached?

Further info:
GHE is a bit broken, and it doesn't seem top of the list from the github developers to fix it. Trying to access images from a different domain results in CORB issues. I can get the files I need using octokit, as mentioned above the users do need to login to GHE, so I have access to their access token.

What I want to do is to show markdown information, I get the markdown file through octokit, but in markdown you can of course link to images. These images will often be stored along with the markdown file in github, resulting in either relative or direct urls in the markdown file. I want to render this markdown file along with whatever images that is specified in the markdown file, but as I mentioned earlier rendering it directly will result in CORB issues.

The idea I had was that I instead could swap these GHE urls to urls with the raw token attached, using a url like that for an image would definitely work, and it does not matter that it isnt a permanent url. On the contrary it is more secure with a temporary token, and the urls would be recreated every time the user hits the page anyway, so no need for permanent links.

If I could use the users auth token to create a link to a raw image it would solve my issues, is this possible? If not, do you have any suggestions on an alternative way to do this?

The only other way I can think of is to create a proxy, that authenticates and fetches the files through octokit and returns them. This would however need to use a service account instead of the currently logged in user, which opens up a security hole where users who shouldn't have access to certain files suddenly can use the proxy instead.

Am I missing something?

Thankful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, personal access tokens and other similar tokens can't be used there.  If you want to use a personal access token, you have two options:

- Use [the `/repos/OWNER/NAME/contents/` endpoints](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-repository-content) with `Accept: application/vnd.github.raw` and pass the token in the `Authorization` header.  This will return the raw file, but it won't use the correct content type, so it probably won't render in the browser, but it can be programmatically downloaded.
- Use the same endpoint *without* that `Accept` header but *with* the `Authorization` header and then you'll get a JSON response with `download_url`, which contains the correct token for that URL.

Note that all tokens in raw file URLs for private repositories are temporary and expire after a while, or when the user changes their password.

I will recommend that for your purpose, you probably want to deploy these documents and images to some sort of static server on a periodic basis (say, with your CI system) and host them there.  That's going to be a lot easier than trying to write a proxy.

Comment: The problem with those solutions for me is that I need a direct link to the image, imagine this: 

I have a folder in my repo with ADR's, in one of those ADR's I want to link to a DB schema, I don't want to have to upload that somewhere else I want it in my repo along with the markdown file. 

I use octokit to get the markdown file, it will have a link that looks something like
 
```![dbschema](https://mygithubenterprice.com/MyOrg/my-repo/raw/main/dbschema.png "DB Schema")```

Comment: If I try to render that directly on my site I'll have CORB issues. 

I can as you say use octokit/api to get the files, but that wont help me render the markdown file directly

I can alter the urls after fetching the markdown content, to have them point to my own backend which does the fetching from github and sends back the image (i.e. a proxy). But then I dont have access to the users auth anymore, so it'd need to use a service acc

I cant add headers directly to an image url, since that is handled by the browser automatically

In short I guess I'm screwed, but I'll accept the answer

Comment: Actually, I take what I said back! Your suggestion to use the download_url worked :) it’s a little bit jankier than I would have liked, and leads to two requests per image (one to get the url from js and one from the browser), but it is a lot better than not being able to use images at all! Thank you!